# User input into a script in Powershell GUI

Tags: powershell

hoping for some help. I've got a dialog box that I want to do a certain action and running into issues getting the user input as a variable in the script. Essentially I want the user to be able to copy down a row in excel (so, for example, copy 4 numbers down a line in row E). I want the user to be able to paste it into the powershell GUI I made, once pasted I want the button to use that user input and put it in to a script I have already made and execute using each of those numbers as a variable and to return the output of the script. I've got the script and button made i'm just not sure what cmdlet or functions I need to do in order to take the user input and place in the script as a variable. Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

I went through Microsoft Docs and tried to find a cmdlet but either I didn't understand it or it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please add what you've done so far / provide the code you wrote. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) - [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: There are lots of examples of your use case right here on SO. Just use the search box above, as well as a plethora of samples all over the web/Youtube. This is not a PowerShell-specific issue. This is normal GUI (SDI/MDI) interop/interaction, that one would do in virtually any language for decades. You pull from the GUI element, via the element attribute or to a GUI element from the backend code using the target element.